# Inexperienced with videos and looking for advice for dealing with incorrect avi framerate and possible alternatives

Tags: bash, video, raspberry-pi, libav, libavcodec

Hi there I am aiming to record 1 hr videos at 500x375) from a raspberry pi (running 64-bit bullseye) which need to be recorded in such a way that they can endure unexpected program termination or system shutdown.

Currently I am using a bash script utilising libcamera-vid and libav:

```
libcamera-vid -t $filmDuration --framerate 5 --width 500 --height 375 --nopreview --codec libav --libav-format avi -o "$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M.avi)" --tuning-file /usr/share/libcamera/ipa/raspberrypi/imx219_noir.json
```

I initially encoded h.264 as mp4 but found that any interruption of the script would corrupt the file and I lack the understanding to work around this (though I suspect a method exists). The avi format on the other hand seems more robust and so I moved to using it but I am having a fairly serious issue by which the file appears to think the video is running at 600fps, rather than 5.

As far as I can tell this is not the case and there has been no loss in video duration that I would expect if the frames were being condensed but the machine learning toolkit (utilising openCV) these videos are recorded for takes the fps information as part of its novel video analysis effectively making it unable to analyse them.

I am not sure why exactly this is occurring or how to fix it but any advice would be very welcome; including any suggestions for other encoding software or solutions to recording to mp4 in a way that avoids corruption.

Comment: I don't have much experience either but I'd first try a format that is used for streaming, like `mpegts`.

Comment: This is supported by pi too will have to check how this would work with openCV but thanks for the suggestion, finding this topic is vast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not resolved as such but after opening an [issue](https://github.com/raspberrypi/libcamera-apps/issues/391) at the libcamera-apps repo this behaviour has been replicated and confirmed to be unintended.

While a similar issue that was effecting the mkv format incorrectly reporting its fps (as 30 according `ffprobe`) has been fixed, currently the issue with avi files incorrectly reporting fps has not.

Edit: New update to the libcamera-apps has now fixed the avi issue as well according to latest [commit](https://github.com/raspberrypi/libcamera-apps/pull/392).